# Random SKColor in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I was wondering how I would be able to choose a random SKColor for a node out of Red, Blue or Green color?

At the moment, I am just setting the Node color by block.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use create with red/green/blue:

```
SKColor(red:   Float(arc4random_uniform(255))/255.0,
        green: Float(arc4random_uniform(255))/255.0 , 
        blue:  Float(arc4random_uniform(255))/255.0 ,
        alpha: 1.0)
```

This will generate a random color. You can use the same principle in the HSV space....

Another version if you create a randomTo1() func which return a CGFloat random number from 0 to 1:

```
func randomTo1() -> CGFloat{
    return CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255))/255.0 
}
let color=SKColor(red: randomTo1(),green: randomTo1(), blue: randomTo1(), alpha:1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! I am using the code you gave me, however there are some minor errors I'm trying to fix.

block.fillColor = SKColor(red: arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0,green: arc4random_uniform (255)/255.0 , blue: arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0 ,alpha:1.0)

"binary operator cannot be applied to UInt32 and Double"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for RGB and HSB:

```
func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
}

func trulyRandomColor() -> SKColor {
    return SKColor(red: random(), green: random(), blue: random(), alpha: 1.0)
}

func niceRandomColor() -> SKColor {
    return SKColor(hue: random(), saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

EDIT: Something like this works if you only need certain colors and want to choose randomly between them:

```
import GameKit

struct ColorGenerator {
    private let distribution : GKRandomDistribution
    private let possibleColors = [
        SKColor.redColor(),
        SKColor.blueColor(),
        SKColor.greenColor(),
        SKColor.purpleColor(),
        SKColor.yellowColor(),
        SKColor.brownColor(),
        SKColor.whiteColor()
    ]

    init() {
        distribution = GKShuffledDistribution(lowestValue: 0, highestValue: possibleColors.count - 1)
    }

    func random() -> SKColor {
        return possibleColors[distribution.nextInt()]
    }
}

let generator = ColorGenerator()
for _ in 1...100 {
    generator.random()
}
```

I used `GKShuffledDistribution` here to avoid colors being repeated and to make it look more "random" (even though it's not). You could also replace it with `GKRandomDistribution`, but then you'd maybe have 5 times the same colour in a row which isn't very desirable usually.

Comment: Thanks Kametrixom. I love the code. Very nice. How do I limit it to only a selected about of colors? like red, pink, blue, green etc

Comment: Thanks Kametrixom. One more question, the code you gave me before:

func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
}

func trulyRandomColor() -> SKColor {
    return SKColor(red: random(), green: random(), blue: random(), alpha: 1.0)
}

func niceRandomColor() -> SKColor {
    return SKColor(hue: random(), saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

is there anyway to assign a value to each random color that appears?

Comment: @Questions You can just use an array and append every color that appears